# Способ получения всех совпадений шаблона на ruby

Tags: ruby

Добрый день.

Такой вопрос.
В руби метод match возращает первое вхождение в шаблон и не проверяет, есть ли еще совпадения? Каким образом можно добиться, чтобы вернуть все, что попалось под критерии шаблона? 
Возможно ли это сделать с match или нужен какой-то другой метод?

**Вот для примера код:**

```
require 'open-uri'

require 'nokogiri'

def connect(source)  
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(source))
end

emails =[]

email_reg = /^[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/

source = 'http://www.zooton.net/ind7.html'

begin

str =  email_reg.match(connect(source))

rescue OpenURI::HTTPError

puts "Не правильный имейл"

end

emails.push str.to_s

p emails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я открыл Яндекс, набрал "ruby match"...

Первая ссылка привела меня сюда: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80357/match-all-occurrences-of-a-regex)

Там написано: 
Используйте `string.scan(/regex/)`
[link text](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan)

Comment: Спасибо, я думал об этом варианте решения, 
но что-то не решился, и плохо искал (, хоть и пытался...

Comment: Бывает : )